# Matrix in excel vba

Tags: excel, matrix, vba

Can someone help me with finding an absolute sum of all the values above the main diagonal in a matrix?

```
 Sub Tee_Mass_1()
  Dim aa, bb, m, n, i, j, alg As Range, algaeg
  aa = InputBox("Minimaalne arv?", , -100)
  bb = InputBox("Maksimaalne arv?", , 100)
  m = InputBox("Mitu rida?", , 5)
  n = InputBox("Mitu veergu?", , 5)
  Randomize
  Set alg = Range("ralgA")
  For i = 1 To m
    For j = 1 To n
      alg.Cells(i, j) = Int(Rnd() * (bb - aa + 1)) + aa 
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you realise that aa, bb, m, etc are not dimmed as Ranges but as Variants? You can't comma chain dimming like that in VBA.

Comment: @UrdnotWrex - The code you posted populates a range in a worksheet. It does not an attempt to sum the values above the main diagonal - what have you done to determine the sum? What's not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

AS of my understanding to your question, you want to sum the absolute values of the elements above the main diagonal, excluding the diagonal itself.

The elements above the main diagonal have the property that j>i if the element is (i, j).
Hence, you can add the following code

```
AbsSum = 0
For i = 1 To m
    For j = 1 To n
        if j > i then
            AbsSum = AbsSum + Abs(alg.Cells(i, j)) 
        End If
    Next
Next
```

If you want to include the diagonal , then set the condition to:
    **if j >= i then**